# How to set Particular City/Location in Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I am using this java script code in my asp.net website, to show google map. I want to know that how can i code this if i want to show any particular city in India. e.g. New Delhi India
and how can I get latitude and longitude values for any particular city.

```
</script><script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyCbFg7v3vz-FLzKqCBTZvtUr7iLMV-f-rA" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadEarth(mapdiv) {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var point;
            if (!mapdiv) return true;
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl());
            map.enableDoubleClickZoom();
            map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
            map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
            map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
            var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 17);
            GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml("hii");
            });
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 16);
            map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
            var polyline = new GPolyline([new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
                                          new GLatLng(37.4519, -122.1519),
                                          new GLatLng(37.4619, -122.1819)], "#3333cc", 10);
        }
        map.addOverlay(polyline);
    }
</script>
```